# Product of rotation matrices that map $(0,0,1)$ into $(1/\sqrt{3}, 1/\sqrt{3}, 1/\sqrt{3})$.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, geometry

It seems that rotating a vector $(0,0,1)$ in the $YZ$ plane with respect to the $X$ axis with the rotation matrix:

\begin{equation}
\left (
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \cos \theta & - \sin \theta \\
0 &  \sin \theta & \cos \theta
\end{array}
\right )
\end{equation}

with $\theta=45^{\circ}$ and then rotating the resulting vector
another $\alpha=45^{\circ}$ with respect to the $z$ axis with the matrix

\begin{equation}
\left (
\begin{array}{ccc}
\cos \alpha & -\sin \alpha & 0 \\
\sin \alpha & \cos \alpha & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
\right )
\end{equation}

would take the vector $(1,0,0)$ into $(1/\sqrt{3}, 1/\sqrt{3}, 1/\sqrt{3})$,
but I tried and it did not work.

How can this be done in two main axis rotations? Where am I wrong?

Thanks.

**Update**

Thanks to the Robert Israel and Matt Dickau who pointed out my error:

The angles that do the trick are:
\begin{eqnarray}
  \theta &=& -\arccos \left (\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \right ) \\
  \alpha &=& -\frac{\pi}{4}
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the first rotation you have a vector at a 45 degree angle from the z-axis; rotating that vector around the z-axis with the second rotation will trace out a cone. The z-component of the vector does not change with the second rotation which is why your method doesn't work.

To get the desired result, your first rotation should make it so that the vector has the same angle with the z-axis as the final vector. (That is, the angle whose cosine is $1/\sqrt 3$.)

Answer (score 2):

Work backwards.  Find a vector $(0,y,z)$ in the YZ plane that can be rotated to $(1/\sqrt{3}, 1/\sqrt{3}, 1/\sqrt{3})$ by your second rotation (for the appropriate $\alpha$).  Then find $\theta$ so your first rotation takes
$(0,0,1)$ to that vector. $\alpha$ and $\theta$ will not both be 45 degrees.